# docker pull lookup index.docker.io: no such host

Tags: docker

I am attempting to download centos image in "Docker quickstart terminal" with command

```
docker pull centos:7
```

with result

```
Pulling repository docker.io/library/centos
Error while pulling image: Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/centos/images: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io: no such host
```

I use
Docker version 1.9.1, build a34a1d5

**Update**

This looks like a problem with the DNS visible from "Docker quickstart terminal"

```
$ nslookup.exe index.docker.io
Serwer:  UnKnown
Address:  2a01:1700:2:ffff::9f01

*** UnKnown nie może odnaleźć index.docker.io: No response from server
```

Answer (score 6):

This usually is a proxy issue: if you are using a proxy to access internet, make sure to:

- either set properly your HTTP(S)_PROXY environment variable
- or to use docker-machine create with the right --engine-env option

For instance, on my Windows, using VirtualBox:

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox \
  --engine-env HTTP_PROXY=$http_proxy --engine-env HTTPS_PROXY=$https_proxy \
  --engine-env http_proxy=$http_proxy --engine-env https_proxy=$https_proxy \
  --engine-env NO_PROXY=$no_proxy --engine-env no_proxy=$no_proxy
  aMachine
```

That will create the right /var/lib/boot2docker/profile setting file, with those variables declared in it, allowing docker daemon to access the internet.

The quickstart terminal opens by default an ssh session to the "`default`" VM.
That is the same as `docker-machine ssh default`.
If that `default` VM misses the right docker profile, you can `docker-machine rm` it, and recreate it, this time using `--engine-env`.

Comment: i have the same problem somehow please check my post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52323415/start-docker-tool-box-unable-to-find-image-imagelatest-locally?noredirect=1#comment91614682_52323415