# Can you download Docker images with no Docker in the VM?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I need to be able to download Docker images in Linux VMs that are not allowed to have Docker installed.  Is that possible ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can save a Docker image as a tar file in a computer with docker (you always need docker to use a registry. ie dockerhub). save it like this:

```
docker save -o <path to generated tar file> <image name>:<image tag>
```

then copy the files using cp or scp

or you could use something like [moby project](https://mobyproject.org/) explained in this question before

[How do I download Docker images without using the pull command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37905763/how-do-i-download-docker-images-without-using-the-pull-command)

Comment: Thank you. Moby looks very promising!