# Get Dockerfile for Image in Registry without `docker pull`

Tags: docker, containers

I want to generate/get a Dockerfile for an image that is pushed to registry, one that I don't have locally, without `docker pull` that image. I know it's possible to do this with `docker` CLI if the image already exists locally.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, even when the image exists locally. How would you do that?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37905763/how-do-i-download-docker-images-without-using-the-pull-command

Comment: You can create a tar ball and can load it

Comment: I think you cannot generate Dockerfile even if you load image locally using tarball. All you can do is use "docker inspect <image>" command to get all info about image. then generate Dockerfile yourself from there. even this method have some limitations