# start docker tool-box: Unable to find image 'image:latest' locally

Tags: docker, toolbox

I am newbie into docker did the following:

- couldn't install docker engine on my windows 7, but instead:
- installed docker tool-box (engine should be already included)

the terminal from the docker tool-box shows me the sign of the docker and everything should be good but i face problem with the following:

- cant run the simple image "hello-world"

  > docker run hello-world

  **The Error Message:**

  ```
  Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
  ```
- after login with username and password it appears error (i think it is connected with the same error)

  > docker login

  **The Error Message:**

  ```
      Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: 
      dial tcp: look up registry-1.docker.io on 10.0.2.3:53: no such host
  ```

any idea on how to track the reason of such error messages and find away to resolve and solve such issues?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [docker pull lookup index.docker.io: no such host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33997185/docker-pull-lookup-index-docker-io-no-such-host)

Comment: @DavidMaze could you please explain more what do you mean. remember my friend that i am new to docker technolofy thanks :)

Comment: The error essentially means what it says: from inside the VM, the Docker service can't look up the `registry-1.docker.io` host name.  That's the same thing the linked question asks.  If you need to set an HTTP proxy to make external connections, there's also an answer there that might help you.

Comment: @DavidMaze as i execute this command 
$ nslookup.exe index.docker.io
it gave me the name of the server and Ip address along with this message as well "*** dedomcomdc00.computacenter.com can't find index.docker.io: Non-existent domain"

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: very smart question, and yes, i use the laptop of my compay and therefor i need to be connected to it as i work in home-office,